# Show that $\sin(z)$ is surjective even if $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2.$

Tags: complex-analysis

There are questions and answer in MSE regarding surjectivity of $\sin(z)$. But they all prove that there is a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that ... not a proof that $z$ can be a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

The mapping $w=\sin(z)$ maps the lines $x=c$ for $-\pi/2 \le c \le \pi/2$ to hyperbolas, $v$ axis and lines $u \ge 1$ and $u \le -1$. So it 'looks' that $w=\sin(z)$ maps the strip $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2$ to whole $\mathbb{C}$ as it 'looks' that the hyperbolas sweeps entire plane as lines $x=c$ moves continuously in $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2$. I am trying to prove these 'look's rigorously, that is for any $w \in \mathbb{C}$ there is a $z \in$ the mentioned strip such that $w=\sin(z)$ but I stuck no matter which way I am trying. Proving that the real part of $ \sin^{-1} z =-i \log[iz + (1 - z^2)^{\frac12}]$ can always lie on $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2$ for a suitable choice of $n$ is also impossible!

Is there any way to solve this at all? (algebraically not geometrically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that $\sin \, z=c$ has a solution for any complex number $c$ (by solving a quadratic). By periodicity we may find  a solution with $-\pi \leq Re (z) \leq \pi$. Using the fact that $\sin(\pi-z)=\sin\, z$ we can find a solution $c$ with $-\pi /2 \leq Re (z) \leq \pi /2$. [For example if $ Re\, z\in [\pi /2, \pi]$ then $Re(\pi -z)\in [-\pi /2,0]$].